# Getting "was unexpected at this time" error while running standalone.bat file

Tags: batch-file, jboss6.x

I am getting below error while bringing up jboss 6.4 server in windows by executing `standalone.bat` file:

```
?roundrobin was unexpected at this time.
```

Log:

```
C:\work\jboss-gradle-test\JbossDir\jboss-eap-6.4\bin>standalone.bat
Calling "C:\work\jboss-gradle-test\JbossDir\jboss-eap-6.4\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
Setting JAVA property to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\bin\java"
```

---

```
JBoss Bootstrap Environment

JBOSS_HOME: "C:\work\jboss-gradle-test\JbossDir\jboss-eap-6.4"

JAVA: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\bin\java"

JAVA_OPTS: "-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=3M -XX:-TraceClassUnloading -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms8G -Xmx8G -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true  -Djboss.modules.policy-permissions=true  -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djboss.as.management.blocking.timeout=6000 -DPRIMARY_CONNECTIONS_EAS=primary:\(127.0.0.1\)?roundrobin=false,fresh=false,retry=2,recoverInterval=16000,handlertimeout=25000,overalltimeout=25000"
```

---

```
?roundrobin was unexpected at this time.
```

Comment: What is `standalone.bat` file? Can you post it?

Comment: How do you want help with `code` if you never post the `code`?

Comment: I'm going to assume that you're running some code which includes `%JAVA_OPTS%` inside a parenthesised block and that the closing parenthesis inside your expanded variable is closing your block prematurely. As you have not provided your actual code, all I can do is to suggest you change `)?roundrobin` to `^)?roundrobin` in that variable value.

Comment: *»I don't show my code but I expect you to debug it.«* Perhaps you should rethink this strategy... ;-)